# How to pg_dump an RDS Postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

How can I connect to my RDS instance using pg_dump?

This is the instance's endpoint:

```
<long public dns thing>:5432
```

So I'm running this command:

```
pg_dump -h <long public dns thing> -p 5432 -f dump.sql
```

And getting this:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "brendan" failed:
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "<long public dns thing>"
(<IP address>) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is Amazon's troubleshooting advice:

***Cannot Connect to Amazon RDS PostgreSQL DB Instance***

*The most common problem when attempting to connect to a PostgreSQL DB instance is that the security group assigned to the DB instance has incorrect access rules. By default, DB instances do not allow access; access is granted through a security group. To grant access, you must create your own security group with specific ingress and egress rules for your situation. For more information about creating a security group for your DB instance, see Create a Security Group.*

*The most common error is could not connect to server: Connection timed out. If you receive this error, check that the host name is the DB instance endpoint and that the port number is correct. Check that the security group assigned to the DB instance has the necessary rules to allow access through your local firewall.*

Is there a way to specify my security group from pg_dump?  If so, do I have to get a local copy of that the way that I need an ssh key when ssh'ing?

Is it a mistake to even try to use pg_dump remotely?  Should I be trying to just ssh onto the instance instead, or doing something else entirely?

Comment: is this because you didn't specify the correct credentials? -U postgres or whatever is appropriate for your db?

Comment: `-U postgres` to specify that my username is 'postgres'?...

Comment: yes, exactly. `pg_dump -U postgres -h etc...` or whatever your correct postgres user is. It's usually "postgres" by default as I recall.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Step 1: Create a security group on AWS that has your computer's IP address white listed.

Step 2: Add that security group to the database instance you want to connect to.

Step 3: Run pg_dump.  Make sure to specify your user name (thanks @LHWizard) with the -U command.  In this case mine wasn't 'postgres', so I guess generally you'll have to look in aws to find it.  Also make sure to specify your database's name: in some command line tools there's a -d switch for that, but if you check pg_dump's usage:

```
Usage:
  pg_dump [OPTION]... [DBNAME]
```

you can see that it's a formal argument.
So the whole command (in my case) was:

```
pg_dump -h <public dns> -U <my username> -f dump.sql <name of my database>
```

Notice that specifying the port number wasn't necessary -- I think because port 5432 is THE port for postgres.

Comment: `pg_dump` does include a `-d` switch. this syntax works (9.3+): `pg_dump -h my_host -U username -d target_db > dump_file`

Comment: I just ran across this and wanted to note that the "postgres" user is a convention that exists in most instances as a superuser and would normally work, but that user doesn't exist on RDS specifically. This is likely due to the shared server resources architecture. There is a superuser that you create whenever you create the instance, but you would generally use the user specific to the database you are trying to dump for a procedure like this on RDS.

Comment: This doesn't work if your client version is different form the server. Is there a way to get an SQL dump without using pg_dump?

Comment: @Brendan server is showing a version of 9.6 while ssh to the instance is showing a version of 9.3.2 for postgres db, So pg_dump is failing.Any sol??

Comment: @JissRaphel, sorry friend no clue. Haven't messed with this stuff since 2015 :(

Comment: How to reference a snapshot within pg_dump? snapshot name and ARN name did not work. Tks