# How to take my local postgres db to aws rds postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Need commands and step by step approach which can help me to take my local Postgres DB to AWS Postgres rds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pg\_dump an RDS Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881786/how-to-pg-dump-an-rds-postgres-database)

Answer (score 0):

The **AWS documentation** explains the options and how to do it:

- [Migrate an on-premises PostgreSQL database to Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/migrate-an-on-premises-postgresql-database-to-amazon-rds-for-postgresql.html)
- [Importing Data into PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html)
- [Migrate an on-premises PostgreSQL database to Aurora PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/migrate-an-on-premises-postgresql-database-to-aurora-postgresql.html)

These docs could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my step-by-step process for migration. Please check out the following link
[enter link description here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/migrate-from-self-managed-database-ec2-aws-rds-soumitra-sarkar)