# Export database from RDS then create local copy of postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres database managed by AWS RDS. I'd like to get a copy of that database (data, structure, etc) and create a local Postgres database.

I cannot ssh onto the database instance.

Essentially I want to do something like:

1. pg_dump RDS database
2. download pg_dump file
3. pg_restore file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pg\_dump an RDS Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881786/how-to-pg-dump-an-rds-postgres-database)

Comment: Seems to be the best available answer which is unfortunate for 2 reasons: 1) I expect at some point people will forget to remove the Sec Group hole, or maybe even just leave a hole open in the firewall to everyone on the Internet. 2) The user must have the same version of PG installed as the server. Thanks @AdrianKlaver

Comment: As to 2) the comment referred to a 9.3.2 to 9.6 mismatch. That was never answered, but I'm betting someone was trying to dump forward e.g. use 9.3.2 pg_dump to dump a 9.6 server. That won't happen. You can dump backwards, use a new pg_dump to dump the same version or earlier server.  If you really want control of you database don't use RDS, run you own install on an EC2(or other cloud provider) instance.