# How to grant superuser to role on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I use AWS RDS instance and I understand that this is a managed service with some restrictions. But, I've faced the problem when trying to dump the entire database and dump logical replication subscriptions. I can't dump subscriptions because `pg_dump` requires have superuser role to dump them, but only `rds_admin` has a superuser role, and my `root` user (which was `postgres`) doesn't have these grants. And also I don't have a password to connect under `rds_admin` because it is managed by AWS. What I am supposed to do?

[image: Console view]

I got the next error:
`pg_dump: warning: subscriptions not dumped because current user is not a superuser`

I haven't tried anything because AWS documentation says

> When you create a DB instance, the master user system account that you create is assigned to the rds_superuser role. The rds_superuser role is a pre-defined Amazon RDS role similar to the PostgreSQL superuser role (customarily named postgres in local instances), but with some restrictions. As with the PostgreSQL superuser role, the rds_superuser role has the most privileges on your DB instance and you should not assign this role to users unless they need the most access to the DB instance.

Comment: What is the specific error you get?

Comment: I don't think `pg_dump` requires superuser permissions, it should work just fine using the  role that owns the database [\[1\]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-manageddatabases.postgresql-rds-postgresql-full-load-pd_dump.html) [\[2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881786/how-to-pg-dump-an-rds-postgres-database)

Comment: I got the next warning: "pg_dump: warning: subscriptions not dumped because current user is not a superuser"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a superuser on a cloud hosted database, period. That's one of the many sacrifices you have to make for the benefit of not having to set up your own backups an your own monitoring system.